# Feign Equivalent for OkHttpClient Enqueue

Tags: java, spring, okhttp, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

Using OkHttpClient, I can do the following, which would allow me to send the request and process the response when possible.

```java
okhttpClient
    .newCall(request)
    .enqueue(
        new Callback() {

          @Override
          public void onResponse(Call arg0, Response arg1) throws IOException {
            log.info("Call success", arg1);
          }

          @Override
          public void onFailure(Call arg0, IOException arg1) {
            log.info("Call fail", arg1);
          }
        });
```

Is there a way to do this with Feign? I have enabled the okhttpclient for Feign, if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#async-execution-via-completablefuture

```
interface GitHub {
  @RequestLine("GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
  CompletableFuture<List<Contributor>> contributors(@Param("owner") String owner, @Param("repo") String repo);
}

public class MyApp {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    GitHub github = AsyncFeign.asyncBuilder()
                         .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                         .target(GitHub.class, "https://api.github.com");
```

Because their OkHttp client isn't async you would either need to use

AsyncClient.AsyncClient(client, executorService) or more optimally implement an OkHttpAsyncClient.

or RX https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/tree/master/reactive

```
public interface GitHubReactiveX {
      
  @RequestLine("GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
  Flowable<Contributor> contributors(@Param("owner") String owner, @Param("repo") String repo);
  
  class Contributor {
    String login;
    
    public Contributor(String login) {
      this.login = login;
    }
  }
}

public class ExampleRxJava2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    GitHubReactiveX gitHub = RxJavaFeign.builder()      
      .target(GitHub.class, "https://api.github.com");
    
    List<Contributor> contributors = gitHub.contributors("OpenFeign", "feign")
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
      .block();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this reference, I went ahead with [this implementation](https://dzone.com/articles/asynchronous-api-calls-spring-boot-feign-spring-async) to make async calls.

Comment: That link is a terrible implementation of an async API.  This is not Async `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(externalFeignClient.getRecords(header,header,limit,offset))`.

Comment: Actually, looks like it's just the awkward way that you tell Spring to make it async via a separate thread pool.  https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: you are right @Yuri Schimke, do you have any suggestions how I can use AsyncFeign as a bean through a config class for a Feign client?

Comment: I don't think it changes much, but if you use the AsyncClient.Default it will create the Future for you.  https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/f71849d38746fdc7871bf3b0609c488b36459687/core/src/main/java/feign/AsyncClient.java#L43

Later you can implement AsyncClient for OkHttp to use enqueue.